# AppleScript file permission error when trying to save attachment of mail message

Tags: applescript, mail.app, permission, attachments

As per [various code snippets](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/automatically-save-mail-attachments-using-applescript.php) on the web I am trying to implement a simple AppleScript to save the attachments of Mail messages to a folder.

```
set thePath to ((path to home folder as text) & "Documents")

tell application "Mail"

    set selectedMessages to selection
    set theMessage to item 1 of selectedMessages

    set theAttachments to theMessage's mail attachments

    repeat with theAttachment in theAttachments
        set originalName to name of theAttachment
        set savePath to (thePath & ":" & originalName)
        display dialog ("Saving attachment to " & savePath)
        save theAttachment in savePath
    end repeat

end tell
```

Here is what the dialog box reports when I run the script with one message selected in Mail that has an image attached:

> Saving attachment to Macintosh
>   HD:Users:billtubbs:Documents:20180415_103233.jpg

Here is the error message I get:

```
error "Mail got an error: To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info." number -10000
```

It is raised on the line

```
save theAttachment in savePath
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the permissions issue exactly, but I get no error when I use "file" in the line you are referencing.

```
save theAttachment in file savePath
```

Where savePath is an alias to a file. If the alias already exists (for example as a template that you copy to that location), then you should have no permissions problems by saving the attachment into it.

Answer (score 3):

A few years late to this party. However, in case anyone else has the same problem, this seems to be the necessary AppleScript syntax these days:

`save theAttachment in POSIX file thePath`